# JScrollPane and GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to create two non-editable textboxes (each will contain only one line) with a fixed size, but I want them to be scrollable (horizontally only) because I know the text they will contain will be very long. I want them to be below the two buttons I define below, and I want each textbox on their own row.

Problem is, everything shows up and buttons work as expected, but the textbox won't scroll, although I can somehow drag and select the rest of the text in the box that isn't visible. I don't know if labels are scrollable, would they be a better option?

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame win = new JFrame("Window");
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    win.setSize(400, 300);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    win.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );

    JTextArea master = new JTextArea(1,1);
    JTextArea vendor = new JTextArea(1,1);
    master.setEditable(false);
    vendor.setEditable(false);
    master.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100,20) );
    vendor.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(100,20) );

    master.setText(/*some really long string*/);
    vendor.setText(/*some really long string*/);

    JScrollPane mPane = new JScrollPane(master, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    JScrollPane vPane = new JScrollPane(vendor, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS); 

    mPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible();
    vPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible();

    JButton one = new JButton("Select");
    ActionListener select = new SelectButton(master, vendor);   
    one.addActionListener(select);

    JButton two = new JButton("Run");

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    win.add(one, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    win.add(two, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    win.add(master, c);
    win.add(mPane, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    win.add(vendor, c);
    win.add(vPane, c);

    win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    win.setVisible(true);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Don't, ever, use `setPreferredSize`! [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't, ever, use `setPreferredSize`!  This is overriding the information that the `JScrollPane` needs in  order to make decisions about how the components should be scrolled.  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details.  Instead use the `JTextArea(int, int)` constructor to provide hints to the `JScrollPane`, for example `JTextArea master = new JTextArea(1, 20);`.  Any text longer then `20` characters will cause the `JScrollPane` to display the horizontal scroll bar...
2. Don't add both the `JTextArea` AND the `JScrollPane` to the container.  Adding the `JTextArea` automatically removes it from the `JScrollPane`, which isn't what you want.
3. Use `GridBagConstaints#gridwidth` to control the number of columns a component might expand across to help fix your layout...

For example...

```
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    win.add(mPane, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    win.add(vPane, c);
```

I'm hoping this is a really simple example, if not, you should always make sure that your UI is created and modified from within the context of the EDT.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked exactly as I intended, thank you for clarifying exactly how JTextArea's constructor worked and how it worked in conjunction with JScrollPane, that article by itself confused me a bit haha.